# How to detect broken pipe on input?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, stdin

I have a program that is fed data on standard input through a pipe; `someapp | myprogram`

I hoped `read` returns a negative value on broken pipe; it seems it is not the case. The main loop looks something like this:

```
    int rdsum = 0;
    int rdsize = 0;

    do
    {
        rdsize = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE);
        if(rdsize > 0)
        {
            //[operations on the buffer]
            rdsum += rdsize;
        }
        else if(rdsize == 0)
        {
            usleep(100000);
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    while(rdsum < blocksize);
```

Upon `return 0;`, the program heads straight to exit. Or at least it would, if it happened...

If `someapp` in `someapp | myprogram` ends, or is killed, `myprog` is still alive, appears in the `ps` list.
What is the proper way to detect the feeding application died/ended/was killed, and to quit in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man 2 read`:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file)

So the correct behaviour for you would be to return on `rdsize == 0`.

Return value of `-1` is for errors (or `errno == EAGAIN` if the file descriptor is set to nonblocking) only and when that happens you should

```
perror("read"); // print an error message
abort(); // abort the process or do other error handling
```

Like this:

```
int rdsum = 0;
int rdsize = 0;

do
{
    rdsize = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE);
    if(rdsize > 0)
    {
        //[operations on the buffer]
        rdsum += rdsize;
    }
    else if(rdsize == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (errno == EAGAIN  || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) { // #include <errno.h>
        usleep(100000);
    } else {
        perror("read"); // print an error message
        abort();        // exit and core dump
    }
}
while(rdsum < blocksize);
```

Comment: oh... damn, I spent so many years writing literally hundreds of non-blocking `read()`s, and not a single one blocking (world of RTOS), that once I'm to write a blocking one I completely forget how it behaves... Thanks.